# Pseudo class with column count not working in the safari browser

Tags: html, css, browser, safari, column-count

Pseudo class with column count not working in the safari browser.

I have two screenshots.

**1. Firefox browser screenshot**

[image]

**2. Sarari browser screenshot**

[image]

You can check in the screenshot, The first one screenshot is working in with columns count but in the second screenshot, it's not displaying the dots. Is there any issue with my code?

```css
.columnBox {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.column-count {
  column-count: 2;
}

.accord-mobile-data li {
  position: relative;
}

.accord-mobile-data li::before {
  content: "";
  color: #094CB2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #094CB2;
  left: -15px;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columnBox">
  <p>Without Column count</p>

  <ul class="accord-mobile-data">
    <li>Demo 1</li>
    <li>Demo 2</li>
    <li>Demo 3</li>
    <li>Demo 4</li>
    <li>Demo 5</li>
    <li>Demo 6</li>

  </ul>

  <p>With Column count</p>
  <ul class="column-count accord-mobile-data">
    <li>Demo 1</li>
    <li>Demo 2</li>
    <li>Demo 3</li>
    <li>Demo 4</li>
    <li>Demo 5</li>
    <li>Demo 6</li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, I checked it in `firefox` and `chrome`. **In this case** the problem is with `safari`, this browser **does not** support the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. You can check this out here: [::before](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Abefore) | [::afrer](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Aafter). *Sometimes we just can't have it all* ;-)

Comment: if we use the column count then safari doesn't support the before and after pseudo-elements?

Comment: @user9437856 I don't know, but you can always check it ;-) Like i said and checked earlier.. I have chrome and firefox. Good Luck ;-)

Comment: I tested, When I use column count then I am getting an issue

Comment: @user9437856 Like i said  Sometimes we just can't have it all... But in other hand the rest biggest browsers does support(firefox, chrome,opera, edge) so is not so bad ;-)